# How to query NOT NULL with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have table Test:

```
Test:
id | name 
1  | aaa
2  | 
3  | ccc
4  | aaa
5  | 
6  | ddd
```

I want result where name is NOT NULL:

```
aaa
ccc
aaa
ddd
```

How can i get with:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('Test')->findBy('name', NOTNULL??) <-doesnt working
```

and in model with:

```
$this->createQuery('u')
     ->where('name = ?', NOTNULL ???) <- doesnt working
     ->execute();
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->createQuery('u')
     ->where('name IS NOT NULL')
     ->execute();
```

which is standard SQL syntax. Doctrine doesn't convert Null values into proper sql.

Comment: You can't, you will need to write your own custom methods.

Answer (score 20):

Do it in Doctrine way, from query builder and Expr class.

```
 $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
 $result = $qb->select('t')
        ->from('Test','t')
        ->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('t.name'))
        ->groupBy('t.name')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

there are also distinct() function.

Answer (score 3):

Or just use Doctrine filter:

```
$filters[] = new Filter('name', null, 'notEqual');
```

Then

```
$list = $this->get(yourDBinstance)
        ->setDocIdentifier('TestBundle:Test')
        ->setFilters($filters)
        ->list();
```