# How to query NOT NULL with Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have exactly the same question as [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305468/how-to-query-not-null-with-doctrine), but the last question is 6 years old and new Doctrine versions exist, so I am now asking this in reference to the latest version of Doctrine.

I have table Test:

Test:

```
id | name 
1  | aaa
2  | 
3  | ccc
4  | aaa
5  | 
6  | ddd
```

I want result where name is NOT NULL:

```
aaa
ccc
aaa
ddd
```

This syntax doesn't work:

```
$em->getRepository('Test')->findBy(array('name' => notnull));
```

Is there something similar that will work using the findBy syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no shortcut method like `findBy`, but you can use the query builder:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder(); // $em is your entity manager
$result = $qb->select("t")
    ->from("Test t")
    ->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull("t.name"))
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This will give you all entities where `name` is not `NULL`.

See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html for a reference of all query builder methods, including the ones accessible through `$qb->expr()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the QueryBuilder like,

```php
$query = $this->dm
              ->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:DocumentName')
              ->field('fieldName')
              ->notEqual(null);

$data = $query->getQuery()->execute();
```